# Can't understand an English ellipsis

Tags: phrase-meaning

My issue is Rex Stout’s “Might as well be Dead” (1956)

The dialog from the novella:
"I said shut up. Is it too late to get an advertisement into tomorrow's papers?"
"The Gazette, no. The Times, maybe."

I can’t understand, which newspaper is strictly ready to take the advertisement and which is strictly not (or possibly yes or not).

Answer (score 1):

The Gazette, no: it is not too late to get an ad into tomorrow's Gazette.

The Times, maybe: it is maybe too late to get an ad into tomorrow's Times.

Saying "it is not too late" means it can be done now.

Comment: Thank you!

But is it possible (or not) to understand it like “Gazette, no” – “No, we absolutely not able to get an advertisement into The Gazette” and “The Times, maybe.” – “Perhaps we are still able to get an advertisement into The Times”?


The case is two out of three translations to Russian have this version.

Comment: @Maxim I see the difficulty, but reading on, which newspaper do they try / does the ad get placed in? The question does ask 'strictly' and this answer gives the literal interpretation.

Comment: As I know, afterward the advertisement(s) were in “papers”. Does not specify in which, but some “papers”.

Comment: @MaximKornilov: Near the beginning of chapter 2, after the ad or ads have been placed, we read: _The first reaction was not from a P.H. but an L.C. — Loll Cohen of the_ Gazette. So it seems the ad did make the *Gazette*. Is it too late? For the *Gazette* — no, it is not too late.

Comment: @Tinfoil, that's useful context. I will say that I could see "Is it too late?" — "A: no, B: maybe" going either way in a spoken conversation, that is, "A: no" could mean "No, it is not too late" or it could mean "No, it is not possible."

Comment: I agree that, with appropriate context, it is possible it might go the other way. **Q**: *Is it too late [to place an ad?* **A**: *[In] the Gazette? No — not possible.* But we do have context here that "proves" what was meant.

Comment: Russian native speakers understood this in the same two ways.
Thank you all!